# Loop with var in var file with ANSIBLE

Tags: ansible, yaml, var

I would like to loop on variables that are in a `vars.yml` file but with an identical id here is my example:

In my playbook :

```yaml
     - name: Mise en conformité avec la CMDB
       replace:
         path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/results/wifi.csv"
         regexp: '{{ item.syslocation }}'
         replace: '{{ item.emplacement_cmdb }}'
       with_items:
          - { syslocation: "{{ syslocation_var }}", emplacement_cmdb: "{{ emplacement_cmdb_var }}" }
```

In my var file:

```
syslocation_var: ;test;
emplacement_cmdb_var: ;newtest;
syslocation_var: ;test2;
emplacement_cmdb_var: ;newtest2;
```

I would like to do the same thing :

```
     - name: Mise en conformité avec la CMDB
       replace:
         path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/results/wifi.csv"
         regexp: '{{ item.syslocation }}'
         replace: '{{ item.emplacement_cmdb }}'
       with_items:
          - { syslocation: ;test;, emplacement_cmdb: ;newtest; }
          - { syslocation: ;test2;, emplacement_cmdb: ;nextest2; }
```

But in var file

I hope I'm understandable enough...

Thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaml is.... yaml. A dict in yaml is... a dict. You cannot have duplicated keys in a dict although it is not an error: a linter will simply issue a warning except that the last definition wins. So for essence:

```yaml
a: 1
a: 2
a: 3
```

results in

```yaml
a: 3
```

Now, you say that you want to do the same thing as in:

```yaml
       with_items:
          - { syslocation: ;test;, emplacement_cmdb: ;newtest; }
          - { syslocation: ;test2;, emplacement_cmdb: ;nextest2; }
```

You are actually looping on a list of dicts which could also be written as:

```yaml
       with_items:
          - syslocation: ;test;
            emplacement_cmdb: ;newtest;
          - syslocation: ;test2;
            emplacement_cmdb: ;nextest2;
```

You simply have to define a var in your `vars.yml` file:

```yaml
mes_entrees_cmdb:
  - syslocation: ;test;
    emplacement_cmdb: ;newtest;
  - syslocation: ;test2;
    emplacement_cmdb: ;nextest2;
```

Then load that file either in a `vars_files` section in your play or in a task with `include_vars`. And finally loop on that variable in your task:

```yaml
     - name: Mise en conformité avec la CMDB
       replace:
         path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/results/wifi.csv"
         regexp: '{{ item.syslocation }}'
         replace: '{{ item.emplacement_cmdb }}'
       with_items: "{{ mes_entrees_cmdb }}"
```

Comment: Perfect :) It worked .   Ii did the same things for my var file but it I did not find for the part playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file

```yaml
  my_vars: "{{ lookup('file', 'vars.yml').splitlines()|
               map('from_yaml')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_vars:
  - syslocation_var: ;test;
  - emplacement_cmdb_var: ;newtest;
  - syslocation_var: ;test2;
  - emplacement_cmdb_var: ;newtest2;
```

Create the list

```yaml
  my_list: "{{ my_vars[::2]|zip(my_vars[1::2])|
               map('combine')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_list:
  - emplacement_cmdb_var: ;newtest;
    syslocation_var: ;test;
  - emplacement_cmdb_var: ;newtest2;
    syslocation_var: ;test2;
```

Test the iteration

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          regexp: '{{ item.syslocation_var }}'
          replace: '{{ item.emplacement_cmdb_var }}'
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    regexp: ';test;'
    replace: ';newtest;'

  msg: |-
    regexp: ';test2;'
    replace: ';newtest2;'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_vars: "{{ lookup('file', 'vars.yml').splitlines()|
                 map('from_yaml')|list }}"
    my_list: "{{ my_vars[::2]|zip(my_vars[1::2])|
                 map('combine')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_vars
    - debug:
        var: my_list
    - debug:
        msg: |
          regexp: '{{ item.syslocation_var }}'
          replace: '{{ item.emplacement_cmdb_var }}'
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```